# Buyers vs Sellers percent via volume

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wrote this code, works ok but seems a little slow. The output is written to a small table at the bottom of the chart. Seems slow, I don't see any obvious reason why it seems slow, unless I'm missing something.

````
//@version=5
indicator(title="Volume Table ", shorttitle="VT ", overlay=true)

// Finding the current buy/sell volume
buyVolume = (high==low) ? 0: volume*(close-low)/(high-low)
sellVolume = (high==low) ? 0: volume*(high-close)/(high-low)

// Setting the buy/sell color and message
lastBar = str.tostring(volume[1])
sellBuyVolumeMsg = buyVolume > sellVolume ? "Buyers Volume > Sellers Volume": "Sellers Volume > Buyers Volume"
sellBuyVolumeBg = buyVolume > sellVolume ? color.green: color.red

// Find the percentages
buyPercent1 = math.round(buyVolume/volume * 100, 0)
sellPercent1 = math.round(sellVolume/volume * 100, 0)

// Table setting and entries
var table myTable1 = table.new(position = position.bottom_center, frame_color = color.rgb(0, 0, 0),frame_width = 1, columns = 20, rows = 20,  bgcolor = color.white, border_color = color.black,border_width = 1)

table.cell(myTable1, 0, 0, "Last: " + str.tostring(lastBar), text_size = size.auto, bgcolor = color.yellow)
table.cell(myTable1, 1, 0, str.tostring(sellBuyVolumeMsg) ,text_size=size.auto  ,bgcolor = sellBuyVolumeBg)
table.cell(myTable1, 2, 0, "Buyers: " + str.tostring(buyPercent1) + "%", text_size = size.auto, bgcolor= (buyPercent1 >= sellPercent1 ) ? color.green : color.yellow)
table.cell(myTable1, 3, 0, "Sellers: " + str.tostring(sellPercent1) + "%", text_size = size.auto, bgcolor = (sellPercent1 >= buyPercent1  ) ? color.red : color.yellow)```
````

Comment: THere isn't really much going on here. This shouldn't be that slow. You can try putting those `table.cell()` calls in a `barstate.islast` if block.